# Token added to each MetaMask account

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs

I just request a token(Ropsten test net) from one of my "MetaMask" account(Account 1). But MetaMask showing me same token balance from each Account(I have 3 Accounts). Why this token added to each account?
Many Thanks..
i.e:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "sent" tab and then go back to the "tokens" one. Try to refresh the UI in some way.